# Removed Python Anaconda - Python No Longer Working?

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm on Mac Mavericks. I installed and then removed Anaconda version of Python. I was hoping this would default to the system version (2.7.6), but it is not. Typing Python at the command line now does not create the console.

Here is my bash file:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
source /Users/user/.rvm/scripts/rvm
source /Users/user/.rvm/scripts/rvm

# added by Anaconda 1.9.1 installer
export PATH="/Users/user/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

alias python="python3"
```

Comment: Are you actually intending to be running Python3?  Did you run some Python 3 installer after Anaconda?

If not, you should remove the "alias python=python3" line.  You can also remove the "export" line that adds Anaconda to the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter noted, the issue is most likely your `python=python3` alias, as Mac OS X does not come with Python 3. If you want to use Python 3, you'll need to install Anaconda and create a Python 3 environment, or install Miniconda (see http://continuum.io/blog/anaconda-python-3), or you can install Python 3 from python.org.